# Import custom VM image, can it really be true only MBR bootloader is supported?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Was reading the "[Manually importing boot disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-existing-image)" Google Cloud documentation and it says only MBR bootloader is supported.

[image]

I only use GPT and EFI loaders in my environment, this is 2022!

Answer (score 2):

You can import UEFI images as described in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.9/how-to/prepare-vms-servers/migrating-to-uefi-based-vms).
List of supported systems can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.9/reference/supported-os-versions).
When creating an image, add the `--guest-os-features=UEFI_COMPATIBLE` flag as listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#guest-os-features).

To check if an instance supports UEFI, you can run following command:

```
gcloud compute instances describe INSTANCE_NAME --zone=ZONE | grep type
```

If the results includes `type: UEFI_COMPATIBLE` then it can run from UEFI images.

Comment: Thanks :-) So the document I mentioned above is wrong?

Comment: @MrCalvin To import a disk the partition table must have an MBR bootloader (MBR or GPT) and not UEFI. To migrate UEFI disks, use **Migrate for Compute Engine** in the first link. Note: GPT and EFI are not the same things but are related. This often causes confusion.

Comment: Still don't get it, I'm aware of the difference of MBR, GPT and UEFI. Can I import a harddisk image only using GPT (NOT MBR). I assume I can use any bootloader I want incl. EFI.

Comment: As stated earlier, you can import GPT disk image using Migrate for Compute Engine. These documents describe two different processes.